# QTableWidget item color lose when item out of focus?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I set 4th row color to red of the `QTableWidget`, When I select an item and then click the `QLineEdit`, the `Item` color had lose? Can someone solve this?

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import random

class Win(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.le = QLineEdit()
        self.table = QTableWidget()

        self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(list("ABCD"))
        self.table.setColumnCount(4)
        self.table.setRowCount(10)
       
        for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
            for col in range(self.table.columnCount()):
                it = QTableWidgetItem( chr(random.randint(11300, 21300) ) )
                self.table.setItem(row, col, it)
        
        row = 3
        for col in range(self.table.columnCount()):
            self.table.item(row, col).setBackground(QColor(Qt.red))
            
        
        lay = QVBoxLayout()
        lay.addWidget(self.le)
        lay.addWidget(self.table)
        
        self.setLayout(lay)
            

app = QApplication([])
win = Win()
win.show()
app.exec()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the color is not lost.

What you're seeing is the *inactive selection* color: if you look more carefully, it has not the same color as the other items.

There are various possibilities, then.

### Always show the selection color

This is the easiest solution, but has a drawback: the table will look focused even if it's not, since the selected items will always have the same color.

```py
        p = self.table.palette()
        p.setBrush(p.Inactive, p.Highlight, p.brush(p.Highlight))
        self.table.setPalette(p)
```

### Don't show the selection when inactive

This is slightly better than the above, but still not perfect: the selection should always be shown, even with a different color when the view is not focused, but with the following there is no way to tell which item is selected until the view gets focused again.

To do so, we can use an item delegate and just clear the `State_Selected` flag from the option if the view is not active:

```py
class MyDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        if (opt.state & QStyle.State_Selected
            and not opt.state & QStyle.State_Active
            and index.data(Qt.BackgroundRole) is not None
        ):
            opt.state &= ~QStyle.State_Selected

# ...

self.table.setItemDelegate(MyDelegate(self.table))
```

### Blend the background and the selection color

In this case, we blend the background color with the palette selection color, overlaying the `Highlight` color by a factor of half its alpha channel. Note that this might *not* work in certain systems that don't directly use the palette for painting.

```py
class MyDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, opt, index):
        super().initStyleOption(opt, index)
        if opt.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            bgd = index.data(Qt.BackgroundRole)
            if bgd is None or not bgd.isOpaque():
                return
            r1, g1, b1, a1 = bgd.color().getRgbF()
            if opt.widget and opt.widget.isEnabled():
                if opt.state & QStyle.State_Active:
                    group = QPalette.Active
                else:
                    group = QPalette.Inactive
            else:
                group = QPalette.Disabled
            r2, g2, b2, a2 = opt.palette.color(group, QPalette.Highlight).getRgbF()
            a2 *= .5
            factor = (1 - a2) * a1
            a = factor + a2
            r = (factor * r1 + a2 * r2) / a
            g = (factor * g1 + a2 * g2) / a
            b = (factor * b1 + a2 * b2) / a
            opt.palette.setColor(
                QPalette.Highlight, QColor.fromRgbF(r, g, b, a))
```

### Override the painting

In case the solution above won't work, the only remaining alternative is to override the painting of the item. For this situation, the simplest option is to draw the *base* of the item in an "unselected" state (showing the default background), then draw it again with the selected state but with half opacity, and finally draw the item contents clearing any possible background.

```py
class MyDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, qp, opt, index):
        if (opt.state & QStyle.State_Selected 
            and index.data(Qt.BackgroundRole) is not None
        ):
            opt = QStyleOptionViewItem(opt)
            self.initStyleOption(opt, index)
            widget = opt.widget
            style = widget.style() if widget else QApplication.style()
            opt.state &= ~style.State_Selected
            style.drawPrimitive(style.PE_PanelItemViewItem, opt, qp, widget)
            qp.save()
            qp.setOpacity(.5)
            opt.state |= style.State_Selected
            style.drawPrimitive(style.PE_PanelItemViewItem, opt, qp, widget)
            qp.restore()
            opt.palette.setColor(QPalette.Highlight, Qt.transparent)
            opt.backgroundBrush = QBrush(Qt.NoBrush)
            style.drawControl(style.CE_ItemViewItem, opt, qp, widget)
        else:
            super().paint(qp, opt, index)
```

Comment: Your solution is more and perfect, but I think this is a qt bug.When the table item lose focus, the item state is still in `QStyle.State_Selected` state, that is abnormal.

Comment: I try to use  stylesheet, but it can't refine the detail.

Comment: @jettchen No, it's not a bug. The focus is irrelevant for the selected state, that's why I also used `State_Active`. The fact that the view is inactive doesn't mean that it can't have a selection: when you select some text and switch to another window, the selection still remains. Be aware that if you use stylesheets (especially with the `::item` selector), the style and back/foreground is *completely* overridden. It's an annoying issue, but a known and "won't fix" one (at least, for now) since fixing it might seriously affect performance. For advanced display, stylesheets are *not* an option.

Comment: Always remember the last sentence above: QSS (Qt Style Sheets) are extremely powerful, handy, useful and (mostly) easy to use, but they don't come without drawbacks. The basic concept is that they override the default display behavior, just like it happens with CSS in web browsers: Qt widgets are like standard UI elements (like "checkbox" or "select"), and whenever you override a primary component of those elements, you completely lose the default behavior and revert to a basic one. If you really need advanced custom styling, the only option is using QProxyStyle and careful object management.

Comment: Learn more from your comments.